# Javascript concatenation within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

how would I go about concatenating the string of `fAV[0]` with another string to make the value for `fAV[1]`?

This is what I tried but it doesn't work.

```
var fAV = new Array ();
fAV[0] = "#CC0000"; //General colour for text etc...
fAV[1] = fAV[0]+"thin solid"; //Borders
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What doesn't work? Your code should work as expected.

Comment: what exactly is not working? fAV[1] does have #CC0000thin solid

Comment: The code works fine. But, you probably want a space before `thin`. `fAV[1] = fAV[0] + " thin solid";`

Comment: @JohnBupit - Exactly. This is probably a CSS problem rather than a problem with JavaScript.

Comment: Flag for being unclear?

Comment: What doesn't work. If you're trying to create a CSS border, refer to the [MDN Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border). Border's are created in the following format: `Formal syntax: <br-width> || <br-style> || <color>`. If this is your desired intent, then it would be `fAV[1] = "thin solid " + fAV[0];`...

Comment: yeh apologies guys, I was having a brain dead moment and thought something was wrong with my javascript when it was actually just a simple css thing. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript works fine. The CSS is not working because you need to add a space between the color and the rest of it.

```
var fAV = new Array ();
fAV[0] = "#CC0000 "; //General colour for text etc...
fAV[1] = fAV[0]+"thin solid"; //Borders
window.alert(fAV[1]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mUhKV/1/

Comment: Adding an empty space at the end of a color value, are you sure? :)

Comment: depends where else he's using it. put the space where you want.

Comment: Just my opinion but I would place the space at before ` thin solid`. This way you're not altering previous array elements which may be used in additional locations throughout the code. Just a thought...

Comment: thanks guys :) don't know how I missed that one haha.

Answer (score 0):

It is working perfectly:

```
<script>
     var fAV = new Array ();
     fAV[0] = "#CC0000"; 
     fAV[1] = fAV[0]+" thin solid"; 
     alert(fAV[1]);  // it gives: #CC0000 thin solid
</script>
```